# How to see which device uses which kernel module?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, mobile-phone, gentoo

I have a Samsung phone GT-B3210. For some time I was unable to find working Windows drivers for it. I eventually gave up looking. Then one time I was charging phone over its USB port and booted Ubuntu and was pleasantly surprised when I saw phone's μSD card reader on my desktop.

I now need to switch to Gentoo and would like to be able to work with phone there too. Lsusb tells me it's detected as
 `Bus 007 Device 006: ID 04e8:663f Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd SGH-E720/SGH-E840`

but lsmod wasn't very helpful. On the list of loaded modules, I wasn't able to find one which looks like it's related to the phone.

Is there some other way to see which  module is used by the telephone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The USB device should appear under `/sys/bus/usb/devices` as several entries beginning with `7-6` or something similar. Where the `driver` link within the directories point will be the name of the module bound to the device.

Comment: That way seems a bit too complicated for me. I don't hve 7-6. Instead I have something like 7-0:1.0  7-1:2.1  7-1:2.4  7-2:1.0  7-2:1.3  7-1:2.0  7-1:2.3  7-2      7-2:1.2  7-1      7-1:2.2  7-1:2.5  7-2:1.1 When I access those directories, I get links which seem to go in circles. For example 7-1->driver->7-1->driver and so on.

Comment: Don't *follow* the links, simply display their destination, e.g. `ls -l driver`.

Comment: OK. This way interesting modules seem to be cdc-phonet, phonet and cdc-acm.

Answer (score 5):

I find `lsusb` easier and faster to use in such situations.  Example output follows:

```
 $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
...
```

If no driver is used, the line will look like this (the device in my example is a camera for which I did remove the driver from the kernel):

```
    |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
```